# First Order Logic Peano arithmetic Proof

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic, peano-axioms

I'm trying to prove:

$\forall x\forall y((x=y)\longrightarrow(x\not<y)$

I tried starting off with

$u=v, u+s(z) = v\vdash u = v$

$u=v, u+s(z) = v\vdash u+s(z) = v$

.
.
.

$u=v, u+s(z) = v\vdash s(z) = 0$

and try to get a contradiction (since $s(z) \not = 0$, is a theorem), but I'm having a lot of difficulty proving that $s(z) = 0$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *Hint:* prove $u+a=u+b\implies a=b$ by induction on $u$.

Comment: If im able to prove that, how would I apply it to my proof?

Comment: Oh I understand, could you give a hint on how to prove the statement you stated?

Comment: It can depend on the exact forms of the Peano axioms you're using, and/or basic statements that are already proved, e.g. commutativity of addition.

Comment: More specifically, you need $s(u+y) =s(u)+y$ for the induction step.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following lemma:
$$\forall a,b,u:\, u+a=u+b\to a=b$$
This can be proved by induction on $u$, provided we already know $s(x+y)=s(x)+y\,$ (which is another lemma if the axiom is stated in the other argument).

The base case $u=0$ is immediate. 
Now suppose $s(u)+a=s(u)+b$. Then using the above statement, we have $s(u+a)=s(u+b)$. Then injectivity of $s$ implies $u+a=u+b$ which implies $a=b$ by induction hypothesis.

Comment: thanks!, this would just be induction on u right? Not a triple induction on a , b and u?

Comment: I was able to prove this result, but our version of the lemma was $x+s(y) = s(x + y)$, would proving the one you wrote require induction again?